# Will letting the Queen try Rock-Paper-Scissors again change anything?

Tags: alex-kidd-in-the-enchanted-castle

In *Alex Kidd in the Enchanted Castle*, the first boss you fight is 'The Queen of the Oasis':

[image: "I'm the queen of the oasis"]

If you defeat her in Janken (Rock-Paper-Scissors), she begs you to let her have another go:

[image: "Again! I wasn't ready that time!"]

I've tried both options, but other than going through another round of Janken, nothing seems to change. There's no extra reward, no change to the story, or any other indication that allowing the Queen to retry has an effect.

No other boss has this choice to retry - later bosses do *demand* rematches, but you don't have a choice in the matter.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Alex Kidd, why do I feel so old?

Comment: @pinckerman I grew up playing Sega Mega Drive, this game came out the same year I was born!

Comment: I was born the year before :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reward or story/progression/other change for allowing the Queen to try again. This 'choice' appears to be purely for flavour and to give the Queen a bit of personality.

Also note that bosses will always choose specific outcomes for their Janken matches. This is unaffected by the pseudo-random choices made in the other Janken tournaments throughout the game. The Queen will pick:

> Scissors

Then (if rematched)

> Paper

Of course, you can always 'follow along' with the bosses thoughts by equipping a (consumable) necklace.